# Calclulate a multidimensional integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

Suppose we are in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and denote a point in the space by $x=(x_1  , \ldots , x_n$). I'm trying to calculate the intgral

$I= \int_{\partial B_1 \cap \{x_1 \geq 0 \} } x_1 d \sigma,$

where $\sigma$ is the surface measure, and $B_1$ is the unit ball.

I tried to evaluate the integral using diveregence theorem, but I'm not sure about validity of my result. My result is: $ \int _{B_1  \cap \{x_1 \geq 0 \} }  \frac{x_1}{r} dV$, where $r$ is the Eucliean distance $r=(x_1^2 + \ldots x_n^2)^{1/2}$. I also not able to calculate the last integral explicitely (my result is: $I=\frac{2^{n-2}}{n(n-1)}W_0 W_1 \ldots W_{n-3}$, where $W_j= \int _0 ^{\pi /2 } \sin ^j (x) dx$ ).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, by symmetry this integral must be $0$. But if you want to use the divergence theorem, you get:
$$\int_{\partial B_1} x_1 \, \mathrm{d}\sigma = \int_{\partial B_1} e_1 \cdot n \, \mathrm{d}\sigma = \int_{B_1} \nabla \cdot e_1 \, \mathrm{d}V = 0,$$
where $e_1$ is the first unit vector and $n$ is the outward normal vector field, which is just $x$ in this case.

Comment: oh! you are right. I make a mistake in the domain of integration! Thanks! I will edit it.

Comment: in fact I want to know integral of $ \nabla . e_1$ over $B_1 \cap \{ x_1 > 0 \} $. @Klaus

Comment: $\int_{B_1 \cap \{x_1 > 0\}} \nabla \cdot e_1 \, \mathrm{d}V$ is of course still $0$. But since your surface is not closed anymore, you get an additional term from "closing it", which is $\int_{B_1 \cap \{x_1 = 0\}} e_1 \cdot n \, \mathrm{d}\sigma$. Can you solve it now?

Comment: I think you are right and I'm so careless. the domain $D=B_1 \cap \{ x \geq 0 \} $. and my new version is $\int _D x_1 / r dV $. Is the answer in the last line of my question is correct? I'm so sorry for my typos! I was so careless about that. @Klaus

Comment: It seems that $x_1 = r e_1 . n$, because $n= x/r$. $e_1.n= (1,0, \ldots , 0). \frac{(x_1, x_2, \ldots , x_n) }{r }= \frac{x_1}{r}$. @Klaus